# $1=$1 doesn't make any sense

Tags: awk

When going through the AWK [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html) today I found something interesting.

For a long time I've known that `{$1=$1}1` rebuilds the current record and removes extra whitespace, but when reading the documentation it says you can just use `$1 = $1`.

Sure enough, I tested this and it works. But this seems to go against the very fundementals of how an AWK program is structured. IE; `pattern {action}`.

`$1 = $1` is a pattern, as actions MUST be encased in curly braces, as per the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Action-Overview.html).

> An action consists of one or more awk statements, enclosed in braces
> (‘{…}’). Each statement specifies one thing to do. The statements are
> separated by newlines or semicolons. The braces around an action must
> be used even if the action contains only one statement, or if it
> contains no statements at all.

So how is an assignment being done inside the `pattern` part of the AWK program?

Comment: if you peruse other pages of the `awk` manual you'll find the author routinely switches between different formats for displaying sample code ... a complete `awk` script with enclosing braces ... a set of 'action' code within enclosing braces ... a set of 'action' code sans enclosing braces; this page - [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) - shows all 3 types of code blocks; I'm guessing that at some point the author assumes the reader can distinguish between a 'pattern' and an 'action'

Comment: @markp-fuso _"you could have `$1 = $1` as a 'pattern' ... that would always evaluate to 'true'"_ - No, that's not correct. See the examples I made in my answer. For the pattern to match, the value of the expression must be nonzero/non-null.

Comment: that (`$1 = $1`) is not a 'pattern' but rather a general statement about a single action; if you scroll up in that link/page you'll see an `if/else` block that's missing the enclosing braces, too; as for the other code blocks at the link/page that do include enclosing braces, keep in mind that those are complete awk scripts; sure, you could have `$1 = $1` as a 'pattern' with the outcome being dependent on the contents of the first field (see TedLyngmo's answer for examples)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All awk documentation is wrong (or misleading at best) with respect to modern awks when they use the word "pattern" in that context. Talking about `awk 'pattern { action }'` made sense in the 1970s when awk was first invented and some textual "pattern" that could be compared to the input was just about all that could exist in that "pattern" space, see [this article](http://awk.freeshell.org/oawk) I wrote a long time ago listing some of the reasons why "old awk" from that time must be avoided, but some of its issues are actually just because it expects simple `pattern { action }` statements, not full-blown `condition { action }` statements as all modern awks support.

This is "pattern matching" as awk was originally designed to do:

```
$ seq 3 | awk '/2/ { print }'
2
```

The input is being matched against a "pattern" (in this case implemented as a regular expression) and when the input record matches the "pattern" the associated "action" of printing the current record is executed. If that's all that awk could do then `pattern { action }` would (and did in the 1970s) adequately describe its program structure.

Since the 80s, though, you can put so much more in that "pattern" area including function calls, comparing strings, numbers, variables, arithmetic operations, etc., things that can have absolutely nothing to do with the input and so in no way can be considered "pattern matching". It's everything that can go in `if ( condition ) { action }` or `while ( condition ) { action }` or any other context where you'd use a condition with the addition of being able to test a couple of builtin variables like `BEGIN` (the condition that we haven't started reading the input yet) and `END` (the condition that we've finished reading all of the input) which are all also conditions, not patterns.

If we referred to the structure of awk scripts as `condition { action }` rather than `pattern { action }` blocks then it'd be much less confusing for people learning the language. The terminology in the documentation isn't going to change now, though, as it's been that way for 50 years and the word "pattern" is so vague and nebulous that it's hard to argue strongly enough to warrant change that it clearly and definitively doesn't describe the current implementation and so **needs** to change.

You can write `{ if ( $1 = $1 ) { action } }` so you can also write `$1 = $1 { action }` and `$1 = $1` means the same thing in both cases - assign $1 to itself (and also reconstruct `$0` from its fields, replacing every `FS` with `OFS`) and then evaluate the value of `$1` to see it means true (i.e. non-zero and non-null in a conditional context) or false (i.e. zero or null in a conditional context).

Regarding "`$1 = $1` is a pattern, as actions MUST be encased in curly braces," - `$1 = $1` isn't by itself a condition or an action, it's an expression. When an expression appears in a conditional context:

```
$1 = $1 { foo }
```

then its result is tested as a condition and, if true, any subsequent associated action is executed. When an expression appears in an action context:

```
bar { $1 = $1 }
```

its result is not tested as a condition.

All the paragraph you quoted is trying to say is that, in contrast to `if (condition) { action }` which you can write as `if (condition) action` instead if `action` is a single statement such as `print`, you must write `condition { action }`, you can't leave out the curly braces and write `condition action` or `(condition) action` even if `action` is single statement.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response here Ed. I'll mark this as the answer as this clears up my confusion.

Comment: You're welcome. I see in comments you had some questions about why awk treats certain values as numbers vs strings in different contexts too - ask a new question about that if you still have any questions about it.

Comment: @EdMorton : "you can't leave out the curly braces and write condition action or (condition) action even if action is single statement" :::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::  ::::::::: `printf '%s' $'car\tprice\n___\t_____\nRS6 133799\nDeLorean 8999999'  | awk 'NR < 3 || $2 = sprintf("%\47.2f", $2)' OFS=' | $ '` :::: `car price` :: `___ _____
RS6 | $ 133,799.00
DeLorean | $ 8,999,999.00` ::::: as long as the action doesn't involve end-point statements like `print / printf / delete / exit` etc, one can simply write the inverted condition and handle both without the `{ … }`

Comment: `NR < 3 || $2 = sprintf("%\47.2f", $2)` is not a `condition action` pair it's `condition { print }` with `NR < 3 || $2 = sprintf("%\47.2f", $2)` being the condition (the result of an assignment expression and/or function call expression, like other expressions, can be tested in a condition) and `{ print }` being the default implicit action given a true condition. If you could write `(NR < 3) $2 = sprintf("%\47.2f", $2)`  without an implicit `print` action happening like you can write `{ if (NR < 3) $2 = sprintf("%\47.2f", $2) }` then THAT would be `condition action` but you can't.

Comment: Another way to think of it: An awk script is made up of `condition { action }` statements. If you  write `awk 'foo'` with no explicit action then that's equivalent to writing `foo { print }` and the default action, `print`, is executed if `foo` evaluates to true. So, if `print` is the `action` then what is `foo`? It's a condition as that's the only other possibility and it's being tested for a true/false result as conditions always are.

Comment: Now replace `foo` with `NR < 3 || $2 = sprintf("%\47.2f", $2)` and that is also equivalent to `NR < 3 || $2 = sprintf("%\47.2f", $2) { print }` and will also cause the default action of `print` to be executed if it evaluates to true and so `NR < 3 || $2 = sprintf("%\47.2f", $2)` is neither an action nor a `condition { action }`, it's just a condition, same as `foo` or anything else in that context.

Answer (score 1):

[Pattern Elements](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pattern-Overview.html)

> ***expression*** - A single expression. It matches when its value is nonzero (if a number) or non-null (if a string). (See [Expressions as Patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Expression-Patterns.html).)

This means that the single expression `$1 = $1` *is* a valid pattern - and as per the documentation, none of these examples will print anything:

```bash
echo "0 hello world" | awk '$1 = $1'
echo "0 hello world" | awk '$1 = $1 { print }'
echo "hello world" | awk -Fh '$1 = $1'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but why do these not work?

`echo "0 hello world" | awk '$1 = $1'`
`echo "0 hello world" | awk '$1 = $1 { print }'`

A string that is "0" is true in awk, and should match?

>There is a surprising consequence of the “nonzero or non-null” rule: the string constant "0" is actually true, because it is non-null. 

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Truth-Values.html

Comment: @the_slug Documentation says that "The pattern matches if the expression’s value is nonzero (if a number)". So in case of `echo "0 hello" |awk 'S1=$1'` , `$1` is evaluated as number `0` and not as string , meaning that `0=0` and this returns `0` = nothing printed

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou yes that makes sense. But why is a string being converted to a number? If I do the same with "1" it prints as expected and no conversion is performed. So why the difference?

Comment: @the_slug Try this one: `echo "hello 0" |awk '$1=$2'` - nothing printed since `0` is asigned to `$1`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Thanks. But I feel like I'm coming away with more questions than answers here. Why is awk converting the string "0" to a number? I understand that 0 is NULL so doesn't match, but the string "0" is True, so should match. 

And why does $1=$1 cause this conversion to occur?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Figured it out.

`echo "1 hello " |awk '{print typeof($1)}'
strnum`

>Fields, getline input, FILENAME, ARGV elements, ENVIRON elements, and the elements of an array created by match(), split(), and patsplit() that are numeric strings have the strnum attribute.37 Otherwise, they have the string attribute. Uninitialized variables also have the strnum attribute.

Comment: @the_slug OK - Glad you figured it out. This explains why  `echo "hello" | awk '$1=0+3+3'`  will print just `6` and not `0+3+3`

Answer (score -4):

`$1 = $1` requires exception handling when

> `awk 'NF += ! NF'`

handles all scenarios.

If you don't mind skipping lines with nothing but `[ ]` spaces and/or `\t` tabs, then it's even simpler...

> `awk NF=NF`

...with the added bonus being it's perfectly safe to run without any quotation marks